# Unable to add values from a map to a List in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

**Scenario**

I have a serialized Json response from an API as follows:

```
"dropdownValues": "{\"Business Profits to Parents\":\"Business Profits to Parents\",\"Business Travel\":\"Business Travel\",\"Family Maintenance\":\"Family Maintenance\",\"Salary\":\"Salary\", \"Savings\":\"Savings\", \"Medical Expenses\":\"Medical Expenses\", \"Tuition Fees\":\"Tuition Fees\", \"Education Support\":\"Education Support\", \"Gift\":\"Gift\", \"Home Improvement\":\"Home Improvement\", \"Debt Settlement\":\"Debt Settlement\", \"Real Estate\":\"Real Estate\", \"Taxes\":\"Taxes\"}",
```

I have decoded it to json as follows:

```
jsonDecode(dynamicFields["dynamicFields"][index]["dropdownValues"].replaceAll('\\', ''))
```

where, `dynamicFields["dynamicFields"][index]["dropdownValues"]` is the serialized json obtained from the API.

The code above gives me a Map<String, dynamic> as follows:

```
    {
Business Profits to Parents: Business Profits to Parents, Business Travel: Business Travel, Family Maintenance: Family Maintenance, Salary: Salary, Savings: Savings, Medical Expenses: Medical Expenses, Tuition Fees: Tuition Fees, Education Support: Education Support, Gift: Gift, Home Improvement: Home Improvement, Debt Settlement: Debt Settlement, Real Estate: Real Estate, Taxes: Taxes
}
```

**Requirement**

I need to generate a **List** of all the values of this map. For this I'm using the following code:

```
jsonDecode(dynamicFields["dynamicFields"][index]["dropdownValues"].replaceAll('\\', ''))
                                                  .forEach((k, v) =>
                                                      dropDownLists[dropDownListsAdded]
                                                          .add(v))
```

**Problem**

Unfortunately, the code above wouldn't execute and I am unable to generate a `List<String>`.

Here, `dropDownLists` is a `List<List<String>>` and `dropDownListsAdded` is an integer.

**Request**

I would like to know why my code is failing and how to fix the issue so that I am able to populate the List of Strings.

**EDIT**

If I use `a` instead of `dropDownLists[dropDownListsAdded]`, I get **Null is not a sub type of String** error.

Here, `a` is a `List<String>`.

Answer (score 0):

The API is returning an encoded JSON string. Let's assign it to a variable called `jsonString`:

`final jsonString = dynamicFields["dynamicFields"][index]["dropdownValues"]`

Next, we need to parse that JSON string into a `Map<String, dynamic>`, which is the Dart JSON format:

```
import 'dart:convert';

final json = jsonDecode(jsonString);
```

The `jsonDecode` function takes care of parsing any special characters. You **do not** manually have to remove the escape characters from the encoded JSON string: `<expr>.replaceAll('\\', ''))`

Since the `jsonDecode` function takes care of all the parsing work. It takes an input JSON string, and converts it into a `Map<String, dynamic>`, you can now access your data with your keys:

`final businessProfitsToParents = json["Business Profits to Parents"];`

Take care to convert the output as necessary. For example, if your API is returning a numerical value (such as double), then you can cast to that:

`... = json["Business Profits to Parents"] as double;`

If you're unsure of the data type, use type promotion to avoid crashing:

```
final json = jsonDecode(input["dropdownValues"] as String);
final value = json["Business Profits to Parents"];

if (value is double) {
  /// treat value as a double
}
```

Comment: I was trying to assign a void data type to the `items` parameter which accepts List<String>. The issue is resolved now.